# Is there any alpha numeric string encoder for PHP other than Hex?

Tags: php, string, encoding

I want to encode some **binary strings** with something like base64 but only with alpha numeric chars. I know bin2hex could do this, but it makes the encoded string much longer (i tries gzcompress in the strings but didn't make much difference).

Is there any other existing encoding method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding

> The most used forms of binary-to-text encodings are:
>
> - [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)
> - [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)
> - [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)
> - [uuencoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding)
> - [yEnc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YEnc)
> - [Ascii85](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85)
> - [BinHex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BinHex)
> - [Percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_encoding)